# ifup overwrites resolv.conf incorrectly?

Tags: debian, networking, dhcp, ipv6, resolv.conf

Debian 12.4 with networking managed by systemd `networking.service`, dual stack IPv4 and IPv6.

I am aware of the many questions asking how to *stop* the system from updating `resolv.conf`, and this is not a duplicate.

### TL;DR

At bootup, `ifup` appears to be overwriting `resolv.conf` (which I want) but doing it "incorrectly" (I think).  The result is that `resolv.conf` ends up looking like this (prefix obfuscated):

```
nameserver 26xx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:201:2eff:fe70:3bfe
```

What is missing here is the `nameserver` entry for IPv4, and the `search` entry for my LAN domain.

### Details

To troubleshoot, I did the following:

- Deleted all current leases in `/var/lib/dhcp`
- Started packet capture on the firewall for DHCP and DHCP6 ports
- Rebooted the Debian system
- Examined the resulting capture file with Wireshark

The findings are:

- The IPv4 DHCP transaction requests, and the server returns, all the necessary information, including the hostname, domain name and DNS server IP.
- The IPv6 DHCP transaction requests the same data, but the response includes only the DNS server address; hostname and domain name are not present in the DHCP6 response.

What I suspect is happening is that `ifup` is correctly setting up `resolv.conf` with the IPv4 data, then completely overwriting it with the IPv6 response instead of combining them.

***THE QUESTION***: What is supposed to happen with DHCP options and `resolv.conf` in a dual-stack system? Another way of asking that is "Who's at fault here, `ifup` or pfSense?"

### Note

Packages `network-manager` and `resolvconf` are not installed, and `systemd-networkd` is disabled.  The network is being managed by systemd's `networking.service` unit.  I didn't intentionally set things up this way, it's what I got by default at installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I suspect is happening is that ifup is correctly setting up resolv.conf with the IPv4 data, then completely overwriting it with the IPv6 response instead of combining them.

Your suspicion is probably exactly correct.

Plain `ifup` (without `resolvconf` or some other means of dealing with multiple sources of DNS settings) has no memory of previous DNS settings nor any way to combine settings from several sources; it's "the most recent source wins", plain and simple.

And on a dual-stack system, DHCPv4 and DHCPv6 are two separate sources of DNS information. Apparently your DHCPv6 server is not configured to assign hostnames nor provide domain name information.

> "Who's at fault here, ifup or pfSense?"

Definitely `ifup`: it's inadequate for your setup in this regard unless augmented with `resolvconf` or `systemd-resolved`. Either of those would provide the capability to merge settings from two or more sources - and DHCPv4 and DHCPv6 on the same physical interface count as two separate sources.

Comment: I tried `systemd-resolved` first, but the result was identical to my original problem (even after a reboot).  Then I uninstalled `systemd-resolved` and installed `resolvconf` and that fixed the issue.  Name resolution on Linux is clearly a case of _"too many cooks..."_ :-)  Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware that, when properly set up, `systemd-resolved` makes `/etc/resolv.conf` obsolete and causes just a backwards-compatibility setting `nameserver 127.0.0.53` to appear in there? When using `systemd-resolved`, the actual nameserver settings can only be seen using `resolvectl status`.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that.  In my particular instance, for reasons I don't fully understand, `systemd-resolved` was unable to handle the dual-stack DNS resolution.  It still insisted on providing DNS only over IPv6.  `resolvconf` worked seamlessly as soon as it was installed, and I don't really have the time to mess with this any more.  I might revisit this in a few weeks when I have a bit more time.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.